# How to check multiple checkbox if type text is not empty

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I got an input that goes like this

```
<input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" placeholder="Something" />

<input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />
```

how can i check the checkbox if the value of number goes more then 0 for multiple checkboxes and inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you have multiple numbered pairs of number and checkbox input, without properties of linking them. Best would be linking them through some attribute/class/code/etc, but if the pairing can always be done by number followed by checkbox, you can use `.next` to get the checkbox following the changed input:

```
$('input[type=number]').change(function(){
      if(this.value > 0)
          $(this).next('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked=true;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgb1279h/)

This monitors the change on any input of type number, checks its value (`this`) and set the nearest input of type checkbox to checked.

***edit***

To check and uncheck the if can be skipped and used directly as the value being set:

```
$('input[type=number]').change(function(){
    $(this).next('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked= this.value > 0;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n47o9xxu/1/)

Comment: Thank you thats what i need but how can checkbox goes unchecked if value goes to 0

Comment: ah, was wondering if you needed that too. From the question I assumed it was a one way street. Added the version for checking and unchecking

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works on sets of elements.  Consider the selectors to select the set of elements you are interested it, and then you can work with the values and properties of them.

```
 var check = false;
    $('input[type="number"]').each(function()
          {
          if (check || $(this).val() > 0)
              { check = true; }
          }
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',check);
```

Comment: I can't understand i got really low skill level with jquery if i got for example 3x inputs with name quantity'.$read['id'].' and 3x checkbox name=productid how can i match each checkbox with each input

Comment: Ah, I did not get from your question that each number input is paired with one checkbox.  As another answer described, you'll need something in the elements (maybe different name for each pair?) that relates them.  Then you can select the right checkbox when the number changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not so clear. Anyway, I image a situation like this:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" placeholder="Something" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />
</div>
```

You can check on increment of the input in this way:

```
$('input[name=quantity]').on('change', function(){
  var isMoreThenZero = $(this).val() > 0;
  $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', isMoreThenZero);
});
```

---

#### Another Solution!

More freedom on html side:

```
  <input data-target="productid[]" type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" placeholder="Something" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />
```

You can check on increment of the input in this way:

```
$('input[name=quantity]').on('change', function(){
  var isMoreThenZero = $(this).val() > 0;
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $('input[name='+target+']').prop('checked', isMoreThenZero);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this work fine for me, Here i contvert array to string with ~ sign, you can use push for array.

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="created" name="today_check"><strong>&nbsp;Created&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
    <input type="checkbox" value="modified" name="today_check"><strong>&nbsp;Modified&nbsp;</strong>    
 <a class="get_tody_btn">Submit</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.get_tody_btn').click(function(){
            var vals = "";
            $.each($("input[name='today_check']:checked"), function(){  
                vals += "~"+$(this).val();  
            });
            if (vals){
                vals = vals.substring(1);
            }else{
                alert('Please choose atleast one value.');
            }


        });
    </script>
```