# Check the checkbox in the same row - previous td if the textbox in the current td is not empty

Tags: jquery

I've found a code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475496/how-to-check-multiple-checkbox-if-type-text-is-not-empty),
so I tried it with the code (which work as expected) something like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BAWANG PERE BALI
<input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" placeholder="Something" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BROKOLI
<input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" placeholder="Something" /><br>

<script>
$('input[type=number]').change(function(){
    $(this).prev('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked= this.value > 0;
});
</script>
```

Because I don't like the appearance of the result like this
[image]

I want the appearance of the result like this :
[image]

So with the same script, I change the html into like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BAWANG PERE BALI</td>
<td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BROKOLI</td>
<td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But then the script not run.
It didn't check the checkbox after I type in the text box.

What I've tried so far is guessing this and that, such as : I change the line in the script which has `prev` into `.prev.prev` but not working, change to `.prev.prev.prev` also not working. I've also tried with `td:nth-child(1).('input[type=checkbox]')[0]` also not working.

I wonder how do I make it work ?
FYI, the html input is generated from SQL loop `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){`
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs are no long siblings, so you can do this `$(this).parent().prev("td").find('input[type=checkbox]')`

To keep it all in jQuery then you can do it like this:

`$(this).parent().prev("td").find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", $(this).val() > 0);`

**Demo**

```js
$('input[type=number]').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().prev("td").find('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked = this.value > 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BAWANG PERE BALI</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="productid[]" />BROKOLI</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity'.$read['id'].'" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much, Carsten